# iOS : nested sections navigation

Tags: ios, nested-attributes

I want to implement nested `uitableview` such that all the categories come in tableview. When i tap on it, it shows nested categories, then its products
hierarchy something like this
it is not the same like Back Button Functionality where it is pushing a view controller, I am able to reload section, but how to perform back functionality,When I tap on header, it goes to back categories.
 someone who has some idea might share, or have achieved this..

[image: required output]

Comment: Can you try to reword your explanation or provide a bit more information on what you want to achieve (i.e. more screenshots)?

Comment: Like view controllers heirarcy, i want to show that in tableview..

Comment: Instead of using separate view controllers

Comment: In this screenshot, when i tap > used cars for sale, it should move to upper level, like stack.

Comment: You could call `performSegueWithIdentifier()` to go to the view controller you want.

Comment: @ILikeTau dear, I already said. I need to replace only sections by tapping their headers, it would replace like reusable cells , not the view controllers.

Comment: Why not keep the current cell labels in an array, and when your header is tapped call your `UITableView`'s `reloadData()` and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` return the correct cell label based on your header section?

Comment: dictionary keys> array >nested array, so when i tap dictionary keys, it goes to specific array, then in nested array, how can i reverse using headers..

Comment: so suppose i add buttons in headers.. it should work, right?

Comment: I got your point.. let me try thanks.. @ILikeTau